# Setting number of rows returned by vector stores

Tags: natural-language-processing, python, language-model

When using vector stores like pinecone or Faiss from langchain, is it possible to set the number of records returned based on similarity search?

For example, consider the following code, is there a parameter that can be set to control number of rows returned?

```
FAISS.from_documents(mydata, embed_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. To directly quote the Faiss official [documentation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki#what-is-similarity-search) for example, this tool can "*return not just the nearest neighbor, but also the 2nd nearest, 3rd, ..., k-th nearest neighbor*".

The code you've mentioned seems to be leveraging a langchain wrapper over Faiss. If you want the ability to determine the number of records (or neighbors) you'd like to retrieve, you might consider interacting with the primary Faiss Python library :

```
D, I = index.search(xq, k)
```

This command fetches the distances D and indices I of the k closest vectors to your query.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you know how I may be able to access this feature from langchain?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "from langchain" part of your question. I think you might find some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76729793/how-to-specify-similarity-threshold-in-langchain-faiss-retriever#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20following%20as%20a%20VectorStoreRetriever,retriever%20%3D%20dbFAISS.as_retriever%20%28search_type%3D%22similarity_score_threshold%22%2C%20search_kwargs%3D%20%7B%22score_threshold%22%3A.5%2C%20%22k%22%3A%20top_k%7D%29#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20following,top_k) useful.